# sockets.io - How to detect user typing in an input form and broadcast to all users

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, socket.io

I have this function on client side (modified):

```js
var textarea = $('#textarea');
var typingStatus = document.querySelector('#typing_on');
var lastTypedTime = new Date(0); 
var typingDelayMillis = 500; 

function refreshTypingStatus() {
    if (!textarea.is(':focus') || textarea.val() == '' || new Date().getTime() - lastTypedTime.getTime() > typingDelayMillis) {
           
        socket.emit('type' , typingStatus.innerHTML = 'No')
        
    } 
    
    else {
        
        
       socket.emit('type' , typingStatus.innerHTML = 'Typing...')
        
        
 
     }
}
function updateLastTypedTime() {
    lastTypedTime = new Date();
}

setInterval(refreshTypingStatus, 100);
textarea.keypress(updateLastTypedTime);
textarea.blur(refreshTypingStatus);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles2.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        
            <input name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5">

            <div id="typing_on"></div>
    </body>
```

i did the necessary code in the server side as well but i think it doesn't work cause its under io.on(connection,function(socket)) but there is no way to detect input or typing condition on server side.

it doesn't work for other clients and only appears for the same user

Is there any alternative i can use to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

References:

- Client API : https://socket.io/docs/client-api/
- Server API : https://socket.io/docs/server-api/
- Cheatsheet : https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

```html
<input name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5" onchange="sendTypingStatus()">
```

FrontEnd - Javascript : Emitting `typing` event and listening `getTypingStatus` for showing 'typing..' on dom

- Emit event `typing` as user types using `socket.emit`
- Listen to `getTypingStatus` message to show 'typing..' using `socket.on`

```js
function sendTypingStatus() {
socket.emit('typing')
}

socket.on('getTypingStatus',message => {
  handleShowingTypingStatusOnDOM()
})
```

Server Side : Listen `typing` event and **Broadcast** to All users except socket that is broadcasting the message using `socket.broadcast`

```js
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('typing',(message)=>{
  socket.broadcast.emit('getTypingStatus', 'typing!');
 }
})
```

**socket.broadcast** will broadcast message to all users those are connected inside `io()` connection

Answer (score 0):

`socket.emit('type', typingStatus.innerHTML = 'No')` does not execute `typingStatus.innerHTML = 'No'` on the other clients. In order to do that you need to be able to handle an incoming `type` event packet on the other clients.

Also, use an event handler on the focus and blur events instead of polling.